# Why am I obtaining "NoReverseMatch at /catalog/borrowed/" error in this Django application?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am very new in Python and Django and I am finding some difficulties trying to implement what is shown by this Mozilla Django tutorial related to how to handle users\groups and permissions in Django framework: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication

I am following the steps illustrated in this tutorial.

First of all, by the Django admin panel, I created the two groups of users:

[image]

Then I created two user and I put the first one into the **Librarian** group and the second one into the **Library Members** group:

[image]

Then following the previous tutorial I worked on the model\view related to the list of books borrowed by an user (an user belonging to the **Library Members** group).

So into my **catalog/models.py** file I defined this **BookInstance** model class:

```
import uuid  # Required for unique book instances
from datetime import date

from django.contrib.auth.models import User  # Required to assign User as a borrower


class BookInstance(models.Model):
    """Model representing a specific copy of a book (i.e. that can be borrowed from the library)."""
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4,
                          help_text="Unique ID for this particular book across whole library")
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    imprint = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    due_back = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    borrower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def is_overdue(self):
        if self.due_back and date.today() > self.due_back:
            return True
        return False

    LOAN_STATUS = (
        ('d', 'Maintenance'),
        ('o', 'On loan'),
        ('a', 'Available'),
        ('r', 'Reserved'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=LOAN_STATUS,
        blank=True,
        default='d',
        help_text='Book availability')


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['due_back']
        permissions = (("can_mark_returned", "Set book as returned"),)

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return '{0} ({1})'.format(self.id, self.book.title)
```

As you can see this model class contains:

```
borrower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

to bind a **BookInstance** object to an User via **ForeignKey**.

As you can see I am also defining the **can_mark_returned** permission on this model.

Then into my **/catalog/view.py** file I have defined this viw that have to be accessed only by the users into the **Librarian** group (that have set the previous **can_mark_returned** permission):

```
class LoanedBooksAllListView(PermissionRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    """Generic class-based view listing all books on loan. Only visible to users with can_mark_returned permission."""
    model = BookInstance
    permission_required = 'catalog.can_mark_returned'
    template_name = 'catalog/bookinstance_list_borrowed_all.html'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        return BookInstance.objects.filter(status__exact='o').order_by('due_back')
```

Following the **catalog/bookinstance_list_borrowed_all.html** template code for this view:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>All Borrowed Books</h1>

    {% if bookinstance_list %}
    <ul>

      {% for bookinst in bookinstance_list %} 
      <li class="{% if bookinst.is_overdue %}text-danger{% endif %}">
        <a href="{% url 'book-detail' bookinst.book.pk %}">{{bookinst.book.title}}</a> ({{ bookinst.due_back }}) {% if user.is_staff %}- {{ bookinst.borrower }}{% endif %} {% if perms.catalog.can_mark_returned %}- <a href="{% url 'renew-book-librarian' bookinst.id %}">Renew</a>  {% endif %}
      </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    {% else %}
      <p>There are no books borrowed.</p>
    {% endif %}       
{% endblock %}
```

Then into the **/catalog/urls.py** file I defined this section:

```
urlpatterns += [
    path('mybooks/', views.LoanedBooksByUserListView.as_view(), name='my-borrowed'),
    path(r'borrowed/', views.LoanedBooksAllListView.as_view(), name='all-borrowed'),  # Added for challenge
]
```

containing the **all-borrowed** path on which I am interested for this page.

**NOTE:** I copy and paste it from the Mozilla tutorial GitHub, I am not understanding why it put this **r** characted in front of the 'borrowed' path, why? Here the GitHub file link:
https://github.com/mdn/django-locallibrary-tutorial/blob/master/catalog/urls.py

Then, from the admin panel, I granted this permission to the **Librarian** group

[image]

After that I perfromed the migration I start my Django application and I logged into with a user beloning to this **Librarian** user group. So I try to access to the page related to the previous view using this URL: http://localhost:8000/catalog/borrowed/

But now I am obtaining this error page:

```
NoReverseMatch at /catalog/borrowed/
Reverse for 'renew-book-librarian' not found. 'renew-book-librarian' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/catalog/borrowed/
Django Version: 3.1.4
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'renew-book-librarian' not found. 'renew-book-librarian' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: /home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py, line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  /home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/django_projects/locallibrary',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 31 Dec 2020 11:08:18 +0100
Error during template rendering
In template /home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/django_projects/locallibrary/catalog/templates/base_generic.html, error at line 0

Reverse for 'renew-book-librarian' not found. 'renew-book-librarian' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
1   <!DOCTYPE html>
2   <html lang="en">
3   <head>
4     {% block title %}<title>Local Library</title>{% endblock %}
5     <meta charset="utf-8">
6     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
7     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
8     <!-- Add additional CSS in static file -->
9     {% load static %}
10    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 202, in _get_response
                response = response.render() …
▶ Local vars
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py, line 105, in render
            self.content = self.rendered_content …
▶ Local vars
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py, line 83, in rendered_content
        return template.render(context, self._request) …
▶ Local vars
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py, line 61, in render
            return self.template.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 170, in render
                    return self._render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 162, in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 938, in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 905, in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py, line 150, in render
            return compiled_parent._render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 162, in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 938, in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 905, in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py, line 62, in render
                result = block.nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 938, in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 905, in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py, line 312, in render
                return nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 938, in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 905, in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py, line 211, in render
                    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context)) …
▶ Local vars
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 905, in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py, line 312, in render
                return nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 938, in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 905, in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py, line 446, in render
            url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app) …
▶ Local vars
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/base.py, line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)) …
▶ Local vars
/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py, line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
        raise NoReverseMatch(msg) …
▶ Local vars
Request information
USER
utente2

GET
No GET data

POST
No POST data

FILES
No FILES data

COOKIES
Variable    Value
csrftoken   
'iD3hPtfJJBZVhspWJCd6lBixHZlQXDGTNNcNxOeXHP8sMPojFWdj44KmuWLhofBt'
sessionid   
'be6093iztc4amp01m5iem5rqs1hpvmfu'
META
Variable    Value
COLORTERM   
'truecolor'
CONTENT_LENGTH  
''
CONTENT_TYPE    
'text/plain'
CSRF_COOKIE 
'iD3hPtfJJBZVhspWJCd6lBixHZlQXDGTNNcNxOeXHP8sMPojFWdj44KmuWLhofBt'
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS    
'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=447d4c8bbf6ab158891dbc085fed8d55'
DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS    
'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=447d4c8bbf6ab158891dbc085fed8d55'
DBUS_STARTER_BUS_TYPE   
'session'
DERBY_HOME  
'/usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle/db'
DESKTOP_SESSION 
'ubuntu'
DISPLAY 
':0'
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE  
'locallibrary.settings'
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   
'CGI/1.1'
GDMSESSION  
'ubuntu'
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID    
'this-is-deprecated'
GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE    
'ubuntu'
GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN   
'/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/ad34faf4_0179_4a5f_b2d2_a59f791e49da'
GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE  
':1.106'
GPG_AGENT_INFO  
'/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
GTK_MODULES 
'gail:atk-bridge'
HOME    
'/home/andrea'
HTTP_ACCEPT 
'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    
'gzip, deflate, br'
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    
'it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'
HTTP_CONNECTION 
'keep-alive'
HTTP_COOKIE 
('csrftoken=iD3hPtfJJBZVhspWJCd6lBixHZlQXDGTNNcNxOeXHP8sMPojFWdj44KmuWLhofBt; '
 'sessionid=be6093iztc4amp01m5iem5rqs1hpvmfu')
HTTP_HOST   
'localhost:8000'
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST 
'document'
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE 
'navigate'
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE 
'none'
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER 
'?1'
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS  
'1'
HTTP_USER_AGENT 
('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
 'Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36')
IM_CONFIG_PHASE 
'1'
INVOCATION_ID   
'717a5ccecd374f5692251368993fbf92'
J2REDIR 
'/usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle'
J2SDKDIR    
'/usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle'
JAVA_HOME   
'/usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle'
JOURNAL_STREAM  
'9:56281'
LANG    
'it_IT.UTF-8'
LANGUAGE    
'it:en'
LC_ADDRESS  
'it_IT.UTF-8'
LC_IDENTIFICATION   
'it_IT.UTF-8'
LC_MEASUREMENT  
'it_IT.UTF-8'
LC_MONETARY 
'it_IT.UTF-8'
LC_NAME 
'it_IT.UTF-8'
LC_NUMERIC  
'it_IT.UTF-8'
LC_PAPER    
'it_IT.UTF-8'
LC_TELEPHONE    
'it_IT.UTF-8'
LC_TIME 
'it_IT.UTF-8'
LESSCLOSE   
'/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
LESSOPEN    
'| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
LOGNAME 
'andrea'
LS_COLORS   
'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
MANAGERPID  
'1639'
OLDPWD  
'/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/django_projects'
PAPERSIZE   
'a4'
PATH    
'/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/bin:/home/andrea/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle/db/bin'
PATH_INFO   
'/catalog/borrowed/'
PROJECT_HOME    
'/home/andrea/Devel'
PS1 
('(LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV) \\[\\e]0;\\u@\\h: '
 '\\w\\a\\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\\[\\033[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00m\\]\\$ ')
PWD 
'/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/django_projects/locallibrary'
QT_ACCESSIBILITY    
'1'
QT_IM_MODULE    
'ibus'
QUERY_STRING    
''
REMOTE_ADDR 
'127.0.0.1'
REMOTE_HOST 
''
REQUEST_METHOD  
'GET'
RUN_MAIN    
'true'
SCRIPT_NAME 
''
SERVER_NAME 
'localhost'
SERVER_PORT 
'8000'
SERVER_PROTOCOL 
'HTTP/1.1'
SERVER_SOFTWARE 
'WSGIServer/0.2'
SESSION_MANAGER 
'local/ubuntu:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1855,unix/ubuntu:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1855'
SHELL   
'/bin/bash'
SHLVL   
'1'
SSH_AGENT_PID   
'1820'
SSH_AUTH_SOCK   
'/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
TERM    
'xterm-256color'
TZ  
'Europe/Rome'
USER    
'andrea'
USERNAME    
'andrea'
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR  
'/home/andrea/.virtualenvs'
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PROJECT_FILENAME  
'.project'
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON    
'/usr/bin/python3'
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_SCRIPT    
'/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh'
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_ARGS   
' -p /usr/bin/python3 '
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_WORKON_CD 
'1'
VIRTUAL_ENV 
'/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV'
VTE_VERSION 
'6003'
WINDOWPATH  
'2'
WORKON_HOME 
'/home/andrea/.virtualenvs'
XAUTHORITY  
'/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS 
'/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP 
'ubuntu:GNOME'
XDG_DATA_DIRS   
'/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
XDG_MENU_PREFIX 
'gnome-'
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR 
'/run/user/1000'
XDG_SESSION_CLASS   
'user'
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP 
'ubuntu'
XDG_SESSION_TYPE    
'x11'
XMODIFIERS  
'@im=ibus'
_   
'/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV/bin/python3'
wsgi.errors 
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
wsgi.file_wrapper   
<class 'wsgiref.util.FileWrapper'>
wsgi.input  
<django.core.handlers.wsgi.LimitedStream object at 0x7f0c0434a070>
wsgi.multiprocess   
False
wsgi.multithread    
True
wsgi.run_once   
False
wsgi.url_scheme 
'http'
wsgi.version    
(1, 0)
Settings
Using settings module locallibrary.settings
Setting Value
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES  
{}
ADMINS  
[]
ALLOWED_HOSTS   
[]
APPEND_SLASH    
True
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS 
['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS    
'********************'
AUTH_USER_MODEL 
'auth.User'
BASE_DIR    
PosixPath('/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/django_projects/locallibrary')
CACHES  
{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS  
'default'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX 
'********************'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS    
600
CSRF_COOKIE_AGE 
31449600
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY    
False
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME    
'csrftoken'
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH    
'/'
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE    
'Lax'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE  
False
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW   
'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
CSRF_HEADER_NAME    
'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS    
[]
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS   
False
DATABASES   
{'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
             'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
             'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
             'HOST': '',
             'NAME': PosixPath('/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/django_projects/locallibrary/db.sqlite3'),
             'OPTIONS': {},
             'PASSWORD': '********************',
             'PORT': '',
             'TEST': {'CHARSET': None,
                      'COLLATION': None,
                      'MIGRATE': True,
                      'MIRROR': None,
                      'NAME': None},
             'TIME_ZONE': None,
             'USER': ''}}
DATABASE_ROUTERS    
[]
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 
2621440
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS   
1000
DATETIME_FORMAT 
'N j, Y, P'
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M']
DATE_FORMAT 
'N j, Y'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y',
 '%b %d %Y',
 '%b %d, %Y',
 '%d %b %Y',
 '%d %b, %Y',
 '%B %d %Y',
 '%B %d, %Y',
 '%d %B %Y',
 '%d %B, %Y']
DEBUG   
True
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS  
False
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR   
'.'
DEFAULT_CHARSET 
'utf-8'
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER  
'django.views.debug.ExceptionReporter'
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER   
'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE    
'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL  
'webmaster@localhost'
DEFAULT_HASHING_ALGORITHM   
'sha256'
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE    
''
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE  
''
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS  
[]
EMAIL_BACKEND   
'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST  
'localhost'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD 
'********************'
EMAIL_HOST_USER 
''
EMAIL_PORT  
25
EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE  
None
EMAIL_SSL_KEYFILE   
'********************'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX    
'[Django] '
EMAIL_TIMEOUT   
None
EMAIL_USE_LOCALTIME 
False
EMAIL_USE_SSL   
False
EMAIL_USE_TLS   
False
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS   
None
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS    
['django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
 'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler']
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 
2621440
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS 
420
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR    
None
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK   
0
FIXTURE_DIRS    
[]
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME   
None
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH  
None
FORM_RENDERER   
'django.forms.renderers.DjangoTemplates'
IGNORABLE_404_URLS  
[]
INSTALLED_APPS  
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'catalog.apps.CatalogConfig']
INTERNAL_IPS    
[]
LANGUAGES   
[('af', 'Afrikaans'),
 ('ar', 'Arabic'),
 ('ar-dz', 'Algerian Arabic'),
 ('ast', 'Asturian'),
 ('az', 'Azerbaijani'),
 ('bg', 'Bulgarian'),
 ('be', 'Belarusian'),
 ('bn', 'Bengali'),
 ('br', 'Breton'),
 ('bs', 'Bosnian'),
 ('ca', 'Catalan'),
 ('cs', 'Czech'),
 ('cy', 'Welsh'),
 ('da', 'Danish'),
 ('de', 'German'),
 ('dsb', 'Lower Sorbian'),
 ('el', 'Greek'),
 ('en', 'English'),
 ('en-au', 'Australian English'),
 ('en-gb', 'British English'),
 ('eo', 'Esperanto'),
 ('es', 'Spanish'),
 ('es-ar', 'Argentinian Spanish'),
 ('es-co', 'Colombian Spanish'),
 ('es-mx', 'Mexican Spanish'),
 ('es-ni', 'Nicaraguan Spanish'),
 ('es-ve', 'Venezuelan Spanish'),
 ('et', 'Estonian'),
 ('eu', 'Basque'),
 ('fa', 'Persian'),
 ('fi', 'Finnish'),
 ('fr', 'French'),
 ('fy', 'Frisian'),
 ('ga', 'Irish'),
 ('gd', 'Scottish Gaelic'),
 ('gl', 'Galician'),
 ('he', 'Hebrew'),
 ('hi', 'Hindi'),
 ('hr', 'Croatian'),
 ('hsb', 'Upper Sorbian'),
 ('hu', 'Hungarian'),
 ('hy', 'Armenian'),
 ('ia', 'Interlingua'),
 ('id', 'Indonesian'),
 ('ig', 'Igbo'),
 ('io', 'Ido'),
 ('is', 'Icelandic'),
 ('it', 'Italian'),
 ('ja', 'Japanese'),
 ('ka', 'Georgian'),
 ('kab', 'Kabyle'),
 ('kk', 'Kazakh'),
 ('km', 'Khmer'),
 ('kn', 'Kannada'),
 ('ko', 'Korean'),
 ('ky', 'Kyrgyz'),
 ('lb', 'Luxembourgish'),
 ('lt', 'Lithuanian'),
 ('lv', 'Latvian'),
 ('mk', 'Macedonian'),
 ('ml', 'Malayalam'),
 ('mn', 'Mongolian'),
 ('mr', 'Marathi'),
 ('my', 'Burmese'),
 ('nb', 'Norwegian Bokmål'),
 ('ne', 'Nepali'),
 ('nl', 'Dutch'),
 ('nn', 'Norwegian Nynorsk'),
 ('os', 'Ossetic'),
 ('pa', 'Punjabi'),
 ('pl', 'Polish'),
 ('pt', 'Portuguese'),
 ('pt-br', 'Brazilian Portuguese'),
 ('ro', 'Romanian'),
 ('ru', 'Russian'),
 ('sk', 'Slovak'),
 ('sl', 'Slovenian'),
 ('sq', 'Albanian'),
 ('sr', 'Serbian'),
 ('sr-latn', 'Serbian Latin'),
 ('sv', 'Swedish'),
 ('sw', 'Swahili'),
 ('ta', 'Tamil'),
 ('te', 'Telugu'),
 ('tg', 'Tajik'),
 ('th', 'Thai'),
 ('tk', 'Turkmen'),
 ('tr', 'Turkish'),
 ('tt', 'Tatar'),
 ('udm', 'Udmurt'),
 ('uk', 'Ukrainian'),
 ('ur', 'Urdu'),
 ('uz', 'Uzbek'),
 ('vi', 'Vietnamese'),
 ('zh-hans', 'Simplified Chinese'),
 ('zh-hant', 'Traditional Chinese')]
LANGUAGES_BIDI  
['he', 'ar', 'ar-dz', 'fa', 'ur']
LANGUAGE_CODE   
'en-us'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE 
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_HTTPONLY    
False
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME    
'django_language'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH    
'/'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_SAMESITE    
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_SECURE  
False
LOCALE_PATHS    
[]
LOGGING 
{}
LOGGING_CONFIG  
'logging.config.dictConfig'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL  
'/'
LOGIN_URL   
'/accounts/login/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL 
None
MANAGERS    
[]
MEDIA_ROOT  
''
MEDIA_URL   
'/'
MESSAGE_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
MIDDLEWARE  
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
MIGRATION_MODULES   
{}
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT    
'F j'
NUMBER_GROUPING 
0
PASSWORD_HASHERS    
'********************'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT  
'********************'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS 
'********************'
PREPEND_WWW 
False
ROOT_URLCONF    
'locallibrary.urls'
SECRET_KEY  
'********************'
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER   
False
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF 
True
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS  
False
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD 
False
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS 
0
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER 
None
SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT  
[]
SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY  
'same-origin'
SECURE_SSL_HOST 
None
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT 
False
SERVER_EMAIL    
'root@localhost'
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS 
'default'
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE  
1209600
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN   
None
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY 
True
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME 
'sessionid'
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH 
'/'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE 
'Lax'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE   
False
SESSION_ENGINE  
'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE 
False
SESSION_FILE_PATH   
None
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST  
False
SESSION_SERIALIZER  
'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'
SETTINGS_MODULE 
'locallibrary.settings'
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y P'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y'
SIGNING_BACKEND 
'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS  
[]
STATICFILES_DIRS    
[]
STATICFILES_FINDERS 
['django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder']
STATICFILES_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT 
None
STATIC_URL  
'/static/'
TEMPLATES   
[{'APP_DIRS': True,
  'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
  'DIRS': ['/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/django_projects/locallibrary/templates'],
  'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug',
                                     'django.template.context_processors.request',
                                     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                                     'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages']}}]
TEST_NON_SERIALIZED_APPS    
[]
TEST_RUNNER 
'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
','
TIME_FORMAT 
'P'
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%H:%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S.%f', '%H:%M']
TIME_ZONE   
'Europe/Rome'
USE_I18N    
True
USE_L10N    
True
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
False
USE_TZ  
True
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST    
False
USE_X_FORWARDED_PORT    
False
WSGI_APPLICATION    
'locallibrary.wsgi.application'
X_FRAME_OPTIONS 
'DENY'
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT   
'F Y'
```

What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I try to fix my code?

Comment: You use `{% url 'renew-book-librarian' bookinst.id %}`, but there is no view with this name (`renew-book-librarian'`).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am asking why on the GitHub page of this tutorial this view doesn't exist https://github.com/mdn/django-locallibrary-tutorial/blob/master/catalog/views.py

Comment: It has: in the `catalog` app: https://github.com/mdn/django-locallibrary-tutorial/blob/c01c194747cace7f14419da20b5b0daca058487d/catalog/urls.py#L24

Answer (score 1):

The mistake probably is in the reverse `HttpResponseRedirect` in the `views.py` of the `renew_book_librarian()` method.

For the argument that's passed to `reverse('name')` pass the correct '*name*', from where the function is originally called.

Answer (score 0):

**catalog.urls** is something you call from **locallibrary.urls**(which has the root urls).

In this case you need to give a app name for the urls in catalog.urls.

```
eg:
app_name = 'catalog'
```

All the urls inside the catalog.urls needs to be called in the template by it's app name.

```
eg:
{% url 'catalog:book-detail' bookinst.book.pk %}
```

When you are just calling **book-detail** without it's app name, then django starts looking at the root urls file where this particular url doesn't exist.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something. The book-detai works fine. My problem is with the all-borrowed view